# Caculation of net profit

Tags: php

Name:

Instructions:

Read the following requirements carefully
Use these files to complete the assignment
Attach any/all files required to complete this quiz to Quiz 3 located in the Course Content section of Blackboard

Comments/Constraints
There is no one solution; however, your code should satisfy the requirements
You will be graded on your solution as well as your code structure, syntax and annotations
You may use any resources available to you (Google, book, homework, etc.)
This is an individual assignment

Quiz Requirements/Scenario

Simple profit from sale of primary home function

Assumptions (for IRS purposes – this really won’t factor into your code, just an FYI)
This is your primary residence
You have owned your home for more than 5 years
If the person is married, assume they have been married for 3 years or more

Rules
Determining net and gross profits
After selling a piece of property, the amount you gross is determined by the sales price minus the cost basis minus the liabilities (commissions, expenses, capital improvements, etc.).
Taxes
To determine your net, you need to factor in the capital gains taxes (if applicable)
When you sell your primary residence, you can make up to $250,000 in profit if you're a single owner, twice that if you're married, and not owe any capital gains taxes.
If you make more than the allowed amount, you pay 15% on the difference between the gross and the allowed amounts.
Quiz 3 base requirements

Using the above, create a function labeled “calculateNetProfit” with the following input parameters: 
Sale price, Total Liabilities, Cost Basis, Owner Status (two values allowed: single or married)
Choose either single or married and ensure that the conditional statements are working
Finally, call that function using whichever parameters you’d like

Above I have instructions on how to calculate the net profit and below is my php code

```
function calculateNetProfit($salePrice,$costBasis,$liabilities) {
    $ownerStatus = "single";
    $grossAmount = ($salePrice- $costBasis) - $liabilities;

    if ($ownerStatus >= 250000) {
        $netProfit = $grossAmount *.15;
        return $netProfit;
    } else {
        echo $grossAmount;
    }

}
echo calculateNetProfit(320000,100000,2200);
```

I was wondering if I am doing this correctly please let me know thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure we're not here to do your homework..

Comment: @Raz0rwire I mean it would help for some feed back

Comment: You're doing fine, you just need to factor in the single / married requirement.

Comment: @Raz0rwire dont speak that way (Moderators hear everything) we cant say these things. BE NICE !

Comment: @Raz0wire I am just using the single requirement thats it not the marriage and how to I factor that

Comment: @Learner Fine, I'll help.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the two concerns (calculating the amounts and figuring out the tax status). Also, you were calculating the amount of tax that would be owed by multiplying by .15, so for readability's sake I renamed a variable and deducted it from the `grossAmount`

```
function isOverTaxThreshold($ownerStatus, $grossAmount){
    switch($ownerStatus){
      case "single":
          return $grossAmount >= 250000;
      case "married":
          return $grossAmount >= 500000;
      default:
          throw new Exception("ownerStatus must be one of [single, married]");
    }
}

function calculateNetProfit($salePrice,$costBasis,$liabilities,$ownerStatus) {
    $grossAmount = ($salePrice- $costBasis) - $liabilities;

    if (isOverTaxThreshold($ownerStatus, $grossAmount)) {
        $taxAmount = $grossAmount * .15;
        return $grossAmount - $taxAmount;
    } else {
        return $grossAmount;
    }
}


var_dump(calculateNetProfit(500000,100000,2200, "single"));
var_dump(calculateNetProfit(500000,100000,2200, "married"));
```

Comment: @Raz0wire what if I want to do the net profit for only single

Comment: @AdilAli then you can just removed anything not related to "single"?